# How to design paginated scrollbar for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollbar

I saw this horizontal RecyclerView with a custom scrollbar. The scrollbar features a dot for each item, the select indicator slides gracefully to the next dot as you slide the items right and left.

The sample can be found below:

[image]

[Example gif](https://i.imgur.com/GTJRYPn.gif)

Please do you know how I can make something similar?

Comment: That is not  `RecyclerView` . it is `ViewPager` search on google about viewpager with page indicator

Answer (score 0):

The result can be achieved by using viewPager. You can refer to Android developer documentation on how to implement viewpager. Brief explanation can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html). For the indicator, you can create circle shape and apply the animation by yourself or there are tons of library out there you can rely with; for example [InkPageIndidcator](https://github.com/DavidPacioianu/InkPageIndicator)